# Re-encode AC3 5.1 audio with variable bitrate using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion, bitrate, digital-audio, ac3

Does the AC3 audio format support variable bitrate encoding?
If so, is it possible to use FFmpeg's `-vbr` option to achieve that?

I'd like to avoid converting from 5.1 to a 2-channel stereo because I've read that FFmpeg doesn't produce good results when mixing the channels.

Comment: Where did you read that at? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's a problem with the option `-ac 2` that's needed for downmixing https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1851. Either way, the question still holds, does FFmpeg support variable bitrate for the AC3 format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ignoring standards

Oh, that awful, misleading thread. The [ATSC A/52A (AC-3) standard](http://atsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/A52-201212-17.pdf) (refer to sections 6.1.12 & 7.8, and also [this post by pandy](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1851&start=20#p6859)) provides detailed info about how proper downmixing should occur for AC-3.

Note that the Low Frequency Effects (LFE) channel may be omitted when downmixing, and I believe that's what `ffmpeg` does.

## Changing default downmix method

If you want to change the downmix method then try the [suggestion by pandy](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1851&start=10#p6750) in the same thread:

```
-af aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:channel_layouts=downmix
```

I did not test this, so I'm not sure it will do what you want.

Also, investigate the `-dmix_mode` private option. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=ac3`.

## VBR

The `-vbr` option is used as a "private" encoding option for some encoders, not as a global option:

> Private options are specific to the given container, device or codec.
>   These options are listed under their corresponding containers/devices/codecs.

...meaning the use of this option and what it does may vary depending on the encoder; if the encoder even supports this option (refer to `ffmpeg -h encoder=<encoder name>`). Other audio encoders may use `-qscale:a` (or `-q:a`) for VBR.

The encoder `ac3` ignores both `-vbr` and `-qscale:a`/`-q:a`.